# Replicating Stata Command bsample, cluster(nr) into R

Tags: r, stata, resample

I am replicating a paper by Clément de Chaisemartin: Two-Way Fixed Effects Estimators with Heterogeneous Treatment Effects.

I face a problem with Stata command **bsample - Sampling with replacement.**

I cannot understand what `bsample, cluster(nr)` Stata command is doing in for loop and what its results are.

I need to convert `bsample, cluster(nr)` Stata code into R.

[sample data view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoxXh.png)

Stata code below:

```
set seed 1
quietly {
forvalue i=1/200 {
    preserve
    bsample, cluster(nr)
    xtreg lwage d81-d87 union, fe robust
    scalar betafe=_b[union]
    reg diff_lwage diff_union d82-d87, cluster(nr)
    scalar betafd=_b[diff_union]
    did_multiplegt lwage nr year union
    scalar did_m=e(effect_0)
    matrix B=B\(betafe-betafd,betafe-did_m,betafd-did_m)
    restore
}
}
```

Comment: Documentation of `bsample` is online at https://www.stata.com/manuals/rbsample.pdf regardless of whether any reader knowing R well has Stata installed. Executive summary: it is taking a bootstrap sample.

Comment: Stack Overflow does not work well as a code translation or writing service.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The State command `bsample, cluster(nr)` is doing a clustered bootstrap - it resamples cluster ids and then takes all the observations in each resampled cluster.  While there would be lots of ways to do this in R, one is:

```r
ids <- na.omit(unique(data$nr))
for(i in 1:nBootstraps){
  samp <- sample(ids, length(ids), replace=TRUE)
  samps <- lapply(samp, function(x)data[which(nr == x), ])
  bs_data <- do.call(rbind, samps)
  ... other stuff ...
}
```

Where `... other stuff ...` are the other functions executed on the bootstrapped data.

Comment: Solved !!! Thank you, Dave Armstrong, for the detailed code! Everything is working well!